# How to format Laravel Eloquent resource response?

Tags: php, laravel

I am implementing **[Eloquent API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)** of Laravel 5.8
I followed all the instructions in the documentation:

Here's what I got:

> app/Http/Resources/TestResource.php

```
class TestResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "title"=> $this->title
        ];
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Test Title"
}
```

I want it to be formatted like below:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Test Title"
    }]
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve the desired output?

Comment: How are you returning the data in your controller?

Comment: @Jerodev I am returning it like this `return new TestResource($data);`

Comment: You have to make array for data and than use json_encode($data)

Comment: @shikha **TestResource** already implements `toArray` method that's why (I think) I am getting the above output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the resource as part of an array with the key `data`. This way you will get an object where the resource is under that key.

In your controller:

```
return [
    'data' => new TestResource($data)
];
```

Comment: Thanks , it helped, I just added some extra brackets to get the required output :)